# Why does my code not work when using await (Discord.py)?

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am coding a bot that changes the channel name when a certain website is online. This is the code I've got and it works perfectly fine until I realised I had to await: `channel.edit(name="website-is-up")` For some reason the error catching just completely stopped working.
Here is my code:

```
async def timer():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(123456) #actual channel id is in my code but I obfuscated it because it thought it might have been private
    while True:
      try:
          response = requests.head(url)
      except Exception as e:
          print(f"NOT OK: {str(e)}")
          channel.edit(name="website-is-down")
      else:
          if response.status_code == 200:
              print("OK")
              channel.edit(name="website-is-up")
          else:
              print(f"NOT OK: HTTP response code {response.status_code}")
              channel.edit(name="website-is-down")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
bot.loop.create_task(timer())
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are sleeping outside of the loop, thus repeatedly making requests without waiting? Also what error checking?

Comment: @mousetail the error checking is the except in the try loop

Comment: So it thinks the website is always up?

Comment: @mousetail no, when it is down everything just freezes until it is back up. This does not happen if I leave out await but then I have discord.py giving me an error

Comment: Maybe fix your indentation first and see if it works with just print statments without discord code

Comment: @mousetail i have another file called test.py that doesnt use discord code, just print statements and it works perfectly fine

Comment: You should also not use `requests` in async context, use `httpie` or `aiohttp` so your bot won't hang while the request is happening. At least until `requests` support for async is as bad as it is now.

Comment: @mousetail sorry but could you give me an equivalent of my current current code in `httpie` or `aiohttp`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `requests` blocks your code so you need to use `aiohttp`. See [`head`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html?highlight=head#aiohttp.ClientSession.head) and its return object [`ClientResponse`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html?highlight=head#aiohttp.ClientResponse).

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    r = session.head('example.com')
    status_code = r.status
    # (int) 200
```